# Should the captions in a figure list include their references?

Tags: thesis, writing, writing-style

The "list of figures" page in my Masters thesis lists many figure captions. Some of these figure captions have references. Should I remove or keep the reference in the list of figures? Definitely the references are always keeping in main text of the report, I just do not know how to handle them in the list of figures.

Comment: *[...] I just donot know how to handle them in the list of figures?* There are two questions in your post. 1) Whether it is right to have your reference tags in your list of figures and 2) how you should remove those tags. The first part seems to be on topic for this site because it is about style of thesis writing, but the second question is not. If you are writing your thesis by means of TeX/LaTeX; you may search about the second part of your question (the technical aspect) in other websites related to LaTeX. Your current question post seems to be too broad to me.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I am asking the first question. IF the answer is KEEP then I donot need continue to ask question two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the thesis preparation guide from your university says nothing about this, I would approach the question by considering the purpose of the figures list.  The point of the figures list is to make it easier to find these key elements of a very large document; the caption fragment is intended to help a reader find the figure that they are looking for.  There are two typical approaches to making these such caption fragments, either of which might be reasonable:

1. List the exact caption for each figure, so that the list can be more complete.  In this case, you should keep the references, since they're part of the exact caption.
2. Make a one-line summary of each caption, so that the list can be more compressed.  In this case, you should remove the references, since you are making a digest in any case.

If you have lots of very long captions, option #2 is probably better, as otherwise it defeats the point of the index.  If your captions are all fairly short, then option #1 is probably better, since it provides a fuller summary of the contents of each figure.